# VS2010 changes resource file references to Version 4.0 although targeting 3.5 Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, resources

We changed from VS2008 to VS2010 for development. But requirement for the installation of the app is still Framework 3.5. Therefore we target the build to this framework.
Everything works fine except an odd behaviour I would like to verify not to be a problem:

If someone edits resources existing entries in the resources.resx and resources.designer.cs change the system.windows.forms entry from 2.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.0.
Example:

Before editing:

```
<assembly alias="System.windows.forms" 
          name="system.windows.forms, Version=2.0.0.0, ...[signature] />
```

After:

```
<assembly alias="System.windows.forms" 
          name="system.windows.forms, Version=4.0.0.0, ...[signature] />
```

This seems to be a reference for ResXFileRef types for Pictures. A line later it says:

```
<data name="mypic" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>[pictureinfomation - referencing System.Drawing version 2.0]</value>
</data>
```

Running the app does not seem to look for version 4.
But I would like to know for sure, that this is not a problem.

Anyone have any thoughts? I have googled quite some time for an answer and did not understand correclty that the ResXFileRef is used for in the Resources mechanism.

Thanks for any hints if my app is still only using 3.5 Versions.

Regards

Comment: I've noticed something similar; namely, converting a solution from VS2008 to VS2010 may silently change projects' .NET Framework target versions.

Comment: There is definitely some transparent mapping going on.  See this thread for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065577/are-dependencies-promoted-in-net-assembly-manifests/4065799#4065799

Comment: Where in the resource files are you seeing <assembly alias="..">?  Trying to recreate this, and I can't find that tag anywhere in the project...

Comment: sorry for the late answer: The lines are together: first <assembly> then the entry for <data>. No lines in-between.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is a bug.

Try to compile the application and deploy it and test.

Also get the properties of dll using 'ildasm'and check

Comment: I did that. But I feared it could be a runtime loaded reference and therefore pose a runtime risk. So I thought someone new for sure what this entry is used for and if/when it is loaded (possibly only VS designer?).

Comment: I dont think that will happen. You can give a test and check it

Answer (score 0):

It has no impact on your application, as the built binaries are still against .NET 3.5.

If this is a bug, you should not be the first one to notice it.